# How to erase from a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uicolor

I have a screen that acts like a drawing pad - you select a color then as you scribble across the view there is stuff painted in. I need a better eraser then the one I have right now. If I just set my eraser to [UIColor clearColor] there is a situation where it appears to erase.. although, there is a drawing under my finger drawing that is processed from a piece of hardware that acts like a wacom/stylus pad. And if I draw under the peice that is "erased" (with clearColor) there is an alpha difference... the layer beneath my finger drawing... Ill provide some screenshots..

[image]

You'll notice the little grey scribbles on the white line. They were erased - I need this to not be opacity .6 ClearColor - I need to be completely 0. Any ideas?

Here is my touches moved code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);

    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 30.0 );

    CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(_strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), components[0], components[1], components[2], 1);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    [self setAlpha: .6];

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;


}
```

Comment: you should use the eraser color similar to your view color to give the eraser effect, since it never clears or erase instead it just hides, using same color as background view may help

Comment: Same issue if I use black...

Comment: check alpha value of color, it should be 1